# Help me understand this equality? (assessing stabilty of critical points of a dynamic system)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linearization

I'm reading through the solution to a question I became stuck on, and I'm struggling to understand why the following is true:

$$ -kx_{\pm}-k_{1}x^{3}_{\pm}-k\xi-3k_{1}x^{2}_{\pm}\xi = 2k\xi $$

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I guess it depends on the problem...

Comment: A very good point, I thought the picture had uploaded, sorry :')

Comment: No probem :) You have to look at the critical points, where F(x)=0. Try using this equation

Comment: Hmm..I think I struggle to understand intuitively why I can substitute that in. So do the first two terms go to zero? What about the second two?

Comment: What book is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamical system is: $\dot{x}=F(x)$

The equation you are asking about concerns the study of critical points (i.e. points where $F(x)=0$) when $k<0$.

The three solution of $F(x)=0$ in this case are $x_0,x_{\pm}$.

You have to exploit the fact that:

- $F(x_{\pm})=0$
- $\vert k\vert = -k \quad$ (we know $k$ is negative)
- $x_{\pm} =\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{\vert k \vert}{k_1}}$, therefore $x_{\pm}^2=\cdots$